# Using a catalog to replace values in a vector in R

Tags: r, substitution, catalog

Im importing data of values and currencies, among other characteristic. The currencies are strings, and i need to substitute all of them for a number id. I do have a matrix with all currencies and ids as a catalog.

My matrices look like

```
main <- cbind(c("toys", "food"),c(345, 45), c("USD", "EUR"))
cat<-cbind(c("USD", "EUR"), c(1, 2))
```

The outcome i want is for

```
main
[toys,  345,  1
 food,  45,   2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
main[,3] <- cat[,2][match(main[,3], cat[,1])]
```

Output:

```
     [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "toys" "345" "1" 
[2,] "food" "45"  "2"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much

Comment: Thanks! Consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `left_join` from pakcage `dplyr`, i.e.,

```
res <- unname(as.matrix(dplyr::left_join(data.frame(main),
                                         data.frame(cat),
                                         by = c("X3"="X1"))[-3]))
```

such that

```
> res
     [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "toys" "345" "1" 
[2,] "food" "45"  "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the OP wanted to match all the elements in 'main' and not particularly a column, we can use `match` and then `replace` the values

```
i1 <- match(main, cat[,1])
replace(main, !is.na(i1), cat[,2])
#    [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] "toys" "345" "1" 
#[2,] "food" "45"  "2"
```

---

Or another option is to create a named `vector` and use that for replacement

```
v1 <- setNames(cat[,2], cat[,1])[main]
main[!is.na(v1)] <- v1[!is.na(v1)]
main
#    [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] "toys" "345" "1" 
#[2,] "food" "45"  "2"
```